Hrefs working fine on VS code Live Server but getting 404 on Netlify deploy
Everything works perfectly using Live Server on VS code but I can't seem to make it work when deployed.
index.html displays fine on the deploy but clicking navbar links or event listeners returns 404 on Netlify.
Here is the navbar HTML:
    <nav>
      <a id="home-btn" href="./index.html">Home</a>
      <a id="about-me-btn" href="./aboutme.html">About Me</a>
    </nav> 

Here is the deploy: https://ciaran-learning-journal.netlify.app/
I have also tried using href="https://ciaran-learning-journal.netlify.app/aboutme.html" and href="aboutme" but still nothing.
